# Convert name with accents to name without accent using HIVE

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I am trying to pass names with accents, for example: **sŕodigër** to names without accents: **srodiger**.
I'm sure there has to be a way to do it, but I didn't find it.

I'm trying this, but it's crazy to do it with consonants too:

```
    concat(CASE WHEN m.first_names IS NOT NULL THEN 
replace(name, 'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu') 
    ELSE '' END
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Pls use `translate()`.

```
   concat(CASE WHEN m.first_names IS NOT NULL THEN 
translate(name, 'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu') 
    ELSE '' END
```

In below example, it successfully replaced ascents with whatever you want to replace them with.
Example[image]

Comment: and this work with the consonants too?

Comment: should be... doc says `Returns the input string with a set of characters replaced by another set of characters.`